# Acoustic, optical, ferromagnetic and antiferromagnetic spin-waves?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, definition, spin-models

In the context of spin-waves I have seen the following words as descriptors*:

- Acoustic
- Optical
- Ferromagnetic
- Antiferromagnetic

which I have seen used together e.g. "acoustic ferromagnetic spin waves" as well as individually e.g. "antiferromagnetic spinwave". I am assuming that acoustic means the dispersion relation goes to zero (see my [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333070/)) as $k\rightarrow 0$ whilst optical means it does not. But I am yet to find any clear cut definition of what the qualification of Ferromagnetic and Antiferromgantic mean. Please can someone explain this to me?

<sub><sup>*The source is not in the public domain but a quick search on your favorite search engine should bring up sources with the individual terms.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

A ferromagnetic spin wave belongs to a ferromagnet, where there is a net magnetic moment, while an antiferromagnetic spin wave belongs to an antiferromagnet, where there is no net magnetic moment.  Does this answer your question?